# Adding day of week to dates in a text file

Tags: ubuntu, text, sed

In a text file containing lines like those

```
%12/29/2012%
```

how can I process it so they include the day of the week?

```
%12/29/2012 sat%
```

Can `sed` do the trick? Maybe using a combination of `sed` and `date`?

Note that not all lines are dates like this, the dates are markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat file | while read a; do date --date=$(echo "$a" | tr -d '%') +"%x %a"; done
```

Then add percent signs with next command:

```
$ sed 's/.*/%&%/' file
```

EDIT:

If you want to skip lines that aren't dates you have to add if-else statement, like:

```
$ cat file | while read a; do if [[ $a == %*% ]]; then date --date=$(echo "$a" | tr -d '%') +"%x %a"; else echo "$a"; fi; done
```

Comment: Oooops I forgot to mention that not all lines are dates, so I suppose `while read` won't work?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `GNU awk`, you could try:

```
awk '(x = mktime(gensub(/%(..)\/(..)\/(....)%/, "\\3 \\1 \\2 0 0 0", ""))) != -1 { print strftime("%%%m/%d/%Y %a%%", x); next }1' file
```

Test:

Contents of `file`:

```
%12/29/2012%
wtf
%12/30/2012%
```

Results:

```
%12/29/2012 Sat%
wtf
%12/30/2012 Sun%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -MPOSIX -pe 's{%(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})%}{strftime "%%%m/%d/%Y %a%%",0,0,0,$2,$1-1,$3-1900}ge' file
```